# Will static HttpClient in webapi triggers any issue?

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I just realized that we should reuse HttpClient other than dispose them again and again. However, as my app is on asp.net, if I don't do this:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
     client.SendAsync(someurl, something);
}
```

Instead, put client in my controller as a static variable for example:

```
public class MyController{
            public static HttpClient MyClient;
       public class MyController()
       {
            ////some configuration for the HttpClient
       }
       public async Task<Model> get()
       {
               await MyClient.PostAsJsonAsync(url, someModel);
               return something
       }
}
```

When multi-users call my api, will it trigger thread related issues?

This msdn article does say PostAsync is thread safe. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_5

Will it apply to my usage scenario? Also if there are hundred of concurrent requests, will single HttpClient cope with that?

Comment: The methods *are* trhead-safe. Do you want to use the same configuration, cookies for all calls though?

Comment: yes, same config. will a single httpclient cope with hundred of concurrent requests?

Comment: The requests are made by the method, not the object. The *object* though holds the cookie container etc, which means that all requests will use the same cookies.

Comment: So you think it should be ok with hundreds of concurrent request (assume cookie and other settings are the same)? I will do some test

Comment: I think the *servers* you call won't be OK with this, or your ISP. Your downstream code may also complain about handling 100 responses at the same time. 
 You'll have to implement some form of throttling. In similar cases I use an ActionBlock with a DOP >1, or a Dataflow pipeline to retrieve URLs and process their responses.

Comment: For example, I need to retrieve 100s of ticket records from airlines (GDSs actually). Given some ... non-optimal implementations by the GDS, if I send more than 10 concurrent requests their front-end web service chokes and throws XML serialization errors. With a pipeline, I can limit the concurrent requests *and* process results withouth waiting for all requests to return

Comment: Hi, Pana, many thanks for this. For throttling, do you use any existing library to achieve that function? For my web api, I could use dynamicIpSecurity setting in web.config, but that will be for the whole app. Do you have better way to do it for individual controller?

Comment: No, I just set the DOP (ie degree of parallelism) setting of each block in the TPL Dataflow pipeline and limits in the input queues. If a downstream queue is full, upstream blocks are also throttled. BTW, that's just throttling, not rate limiting. An alternative is to use eg Reactive Extensions, to ensure requests are sent at a certain rate, or that only N requests are sent per S seconds, as shown in this SO question [Limiting Requests with Rx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37345516/limiting-concurrent-requests-using-rx-and-selectmany). It's just three lines of code