# Is there a way to manage concurrency with RxJS?

Tags: node.js, rxjs

**TL;DR** - I'm Looking for a way to control the number of HTTP requests concurrent connections to a REST API while I use RxJS.

My Node.js app will make a few thousand REST API calls to a third party provider. However, I know that if I make all those requests at once, the service might go down or reject my requests because of DDoS attack. So, I want to set the max number of concurrent connection at any given time. I used to implement concurrency control with Promises by leveraging [Throat Package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/throat), but I haven't found a similar way to implement this.

I tried to use `merge` with 1 for concurrence as suggested in this post [How to limit the concurrency of flatMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26111037/how-to-limit-the-concurrency-of-flatmap), but all requests are sent at once.

Here's my code:

```
var Rx = require('rx'),
  rp = require('request-promise');

var array = ['https://httpbin.org/ip', 'https://httpbin.org/user-agent',
  'https://httpbin.org/delay/3',
  'https://httpbin.org/delay/3',
  'https://httpbin.org/delay/3'
];

var source = Rx.Observable.fromArray(array).map(httpGet).merge(1);

function httpGet(url) {
  return rp.get(url);
}

var results = [];
var subscription = source.subscribe(
  function (x) {
    console.log('=====', x, '======');
  },
  function (err) {
    console.log('Error: ' + err);
  },
  function () {
    console.log('Completed');
  });
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/rxjs/8247/common-recipes/27973/sending-multiple-parallel-http-requests#t=201703261009146257815

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the responses above. My issue had to do with using [rx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rx) instead of [rxjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs) NPM module. After I uninstalled rx and installed rxjs all examples started to use concurrency as expected. So, http concurrent calls with Promises, Callbacks, and Native Observables worked fine.

I'm posting them here in case anyone run into similar issues and can troubleshoot.

**HTTP Request Callback-Based Sample:**

```
var Rx = require('rxjs'),
  request = require('request'),
  request_rx = Rx.Observable.bindCallback(request.get);

var array = [
  'https://httpbin.org/ip', 
  'https://httpbin.org/user-agent',
  'https://httpbin.org/delay/3',
  'https://httpbin.org/delay/3',
  'https://httpbin.org/delay/3'
];

var source = Rx.Observable.from(array).mergeMap(httpGet, 1);

function httpGet(url) {
  return request_rx(url);
}

var subscription = source.subscribe(
  function (x, body) {
    console.log('=====', x[1].body, '======');
  },
  function (err) {
    console.log('Error: ' + err);
  },
  function () {
    console.log('Completed');
  });
```

**Promised-Based Sample:**

```
var Rx = require('rxjs'),
  rp = require('request-promise');

var array = ['https://httpbin.org/ip', 'https://httpbin.org/user-agent',
  'https://httpbin.org/delay/3',
  'https://httpbin.org/delay/3',
  'https://httpbin.org/delay/3'
];

var source = Rx.Observable.from(array).mergeMap(httpGet, 1);

function httpGet(url) {
  return rp.get(url);
}

var results = [];
var subscription = source.subscribe(
  function (x) {
    console.log('=====', x, '======');
  },
  function (err) {
    console.log('Error: ' + err);
  },
  function () {
    console.log('Completed');
  });
```

**Native RxJS Sample:**

```
var Rx = require('rxjs'),
  superagent = require('superagent'),
  Observable = require('rxjs').Observable;

var array = [
  'https://httpbin.org/ip', 
  'https://httpbin.org/user-agent',
  'https://httpbin.org/delay/10',
  'https://httpbin.org/delay/2',
  'https://httpbin.org/delay/2',
  'https://httpbin.org/delay/1',
];

let start = (new Date()).getTime();

var source = Rx.Observable.from(array)
    .mergeMap(httpGet, null, 1)
    .timestamp()
    .map(stamp => [stamp.timestamp - start, stamp.value]);

function httpGet(apiUrl) {
  return Observable.create((observer) => {
    superagent
        .get(apiUrl)
        .end((err, res) => {
            if (err) {
                return observer.onError(err);
            }
            let data,
                inspiration;
            data = JSON.parse(res.text);
            inspiration = data;
            observer.next(inspiration);
            observer.complete();
        });
    });
}

var subscription = source.subscribe(
  function (x) {
    console.log('=====', x, '======');
  });
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use the [`mergeMap`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-mergeMap) operator to perform the HTTP requests and to flatten the responses into the composed observable. `mergeMap` takes an optional `concurrent` parameter with which you can specify the maximum number of concurrently subscribed observables (i.e. HTTP requests):

```js
let source = Rx.Observable
  .fromArray(array)
  .mergeMap(httpGet, 1);
```

Note that a `mergeMap` with `concurrent` specified as `1` is equivalent to `concatMap`.

The reason the code in your question sends all of the requests at once is down to the calling of your `httpGet` function in the `map` operator. `httpGet` returns a Promise and promises are not lazy - as soon as `httpGet` is called, the request will be sent.

With the above code, the `httpGet` will only be called in the `mergeMap` implementation if there are fewer than the specified number of concurrent requests.

The code above will emit each response separately from the composed observable. If you want the responses combined into an array that is emitted when all requests have completed, you can use the `toArray` operator:

```js
let source = Rx.Observable
  .fromArray(array)
  .mergeMap(httpGet, 1)
  .toArray();
```

You should also check out the recipes that Martin has referenced in his comment.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer gave me a few hints to figure out that my sample needed some tweaks. Also that rx != rxjs. rx seems to be dated and concurrency didn't work. Check examples above.

Answer (score 4):

`Rx.Observable.fromPromise` may be useful in your case. Expanding on cartant's answer, try this, where `concurrent` is specified as `1`:

```
Rx.Observable.from(array)
  .mergeMap(url => Rx.Observable.fromPromise(rp.get(url)), 1)
  .subscribe(x => console.log(x))
```

For time based control, this is what I can think of:

```
Rx.Observable.from(array)
  .bufferCount(2)
  .zip(Rx.Observable.timer(0, 1000), x => x)
  .mergeMap(x => Rx.Observable.from(x)
    .mergeMap(url => Rx.Observable.fromPromise(rp.get(url)))
  .subscribe(x => console.log(x))
```